# InputStream of folder in jar returns empty InputStream

Tags: java, jar, directory, inputstream

I have the problem of wanting to list all files in a directory. The directory in the IDE is `src/main/resources/commands/cirno/`, in the jar, it's `commands/cirno/`:

```
/
    commands/
        cirno/
            file1
            file2
```

What I tried is opening an `InputStream` and listing the lines with a `BufferedReader`:

```
    InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("commands/cirno/");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    br.lines().forEach(strings::add);
    strings.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This works in the IDE, the console output is as follows:

```
file1
file2
```

The problem I is that it stops working when packaged as `.jar`. It still works when I open a single file, but when I try to open a folder, the returned InputStream is empty. It is not `null`, as `is == null` returns false, but `br.readLine()` returns an empty String.

Comment: This question is specific about searching resources inside jar file. The linked question provides solution only to unpacked classpath.